# Links on menu not working on click, but work on right click?

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

Top level links on shaperssurf.com mega menu arent working on click but are working fine on right click ( Fins > Thruster Fins, Longboard Fins... etc)

We have another site shapers.com.au that uses the exact same theme and menu and we arent having this issue. mega menu is working fine.

There is a difference in the code that is generated on the links on the 2 websites....

Shaperssurf.com

```
<a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action navPages-action-depth-max has-subMenu" href="https://shaperssurf.com/longboard/" data-collapsible="navPages-1125" aria-label="Longboard Fins" aria-controls="navPages-1125" aria-expanded="true">
                        <span>Longboard Fins</span><i class="icon navPages-action-moreIcon" aria-hidden="true"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-chevron-down"></use></svg></i>
                    </a>
```

shapers.com.au

```
<a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action navPages-action-depth-max has-subMenu" href="https://shapers.com.au/shaping-blocks-1/">
                        <span>Shaping Blocks</span><i class="icon navPages-action-moreIcon" aria-hidden="true"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-chevron-down"></use></svg></i>
                    </a>
```

I have tried disabling some javascript files to see if that would help but nothing seems to work

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you narrowed down _why_ there's a difference between the two examples?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted the **Shaperssurf.com** code in a html with the basic html, and it worked.

I just pasted your code in Visual Studio Code and it works. But it seams that there is some type of error in some like break or what.

Take a look:

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOyu7.png)

But when I just deleted some line breaks.

[Fixed?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3j0V.png)

### Resuming

When the code is pasted in VsCode there some type of error in the line breaks, but with the 'error' or 'fixed' it works normal for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be some custom work done on this theme. The elements in question have data-collapsible and aria-controls attributes on them. This basically defines them as flyout-style navigation elements, and not actual links. Removing these attributes should resolve the issue, but might be tricky to do. You may need developer assistance here.

If you did not have any custom work done on the theme, it is a bug with the theme itself, and I would recommend reaching out to the theme designer.